# backbone model get attribute within initialize method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've looked for a solution to this but cannot find anything that works.

Note: I am overriding the `Backbone.sync` method globally.

When I instantiate a Session model I pass a number of attributes to it. These, as you would expect, should be "gettable" via `mySessionInstance.get('someAttribute')`. The session model calls `this.fetch()` within the initialize method. My custom Backbone.sync method needs to access some of the session attributes but when it runs I get an error saying the "get" method does not exist for that instance.

It's as if I was trying to access .get for my session instance before it was fully initialized. Any ideas on how to fix it? I wish there was a "ready" or "initialized" event for models so I could just listen for that and ensure certain things only happen when the model is truly done initializing.

Thanks,

Luis

Comment: Posting the relevant code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two events that a model [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) will trigger:

1. `"change"` events will be triggered if anything is changed (i.e. if anything came back from the server). A `fetch` is mostly a [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) that is called by an AJAX success handler after all.
2. A `"sync"` event will be [triggered when the model is synced with the server](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-events), syncing includes fetching. The `fetch` docs aren't explicit on this but you can easily see it in [the source](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L336) and the [master events list](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-events) notes it.

The `"change"` event is probably more useful in general and should serve to indicate that the model is ready for use.

If you just need a one-time notification, you could use use the `success` callback from the [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch):

```
model.fetch({
    success: function(model, response) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that. It may be all I need.